# Discord.js Profanity filter detecting hello as a bad word

Tags: discord.js

My code:

```
client.on('message', message =>{
   for (var i = 0; i < profanities.length; i++){
      if (message.content.includes(profanities[i])) {
      message.channel.send('Please do not say bad words.');
      message.delete();
      return;
      }
   }
});
```

How do I whitelist certain words? Or just make hello not be detected or something like that.

Comment: You have to start by comparing words, not just sequences of characters.   One hack is to look for " hell " rather than "hell"; you can handle the end cases by also adding a space at each end of the message.  This doesn't deal with bad words separated by tabs, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) instead of testing if the message simply contains a profanity.

```js
const regex = new RegExp(`(\\b|\\d)(${profanities.join('|')})(\\b\\d)`, 'i');
if (regex.test(message.content)) {
  message.channel.send('Please do not say bad words.');
  message.delete();
}
```

`regex` will be something like `/(\b|\d)(hell|poo|swear)(\b\d)/i` (or whatever the profanities are).

- `(\b|\d)` matches a word boundary or a digit. A [word boundary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#Boundary-type_assertions) is

  > the position where a word character is not followed or preceded by another word-character, such as between a letter and a space.
- `(hell|poo|swear)` matches any one of the profanities.
- Bonus: the `i` flag makes it case insensitive, so it matches things like `hELl` or `HELL`.

Here's a demo:

```js
const profanities = ['hell', 'poo', 'swear'];
const regex = new RegExp(`(\\b|\\d)(${profanities.join('|')})(\\b|\\d)`, 'i');
console.log(regex);
[
  // Will match
  'hell!',
  'hELL',
  'hell-something',
  'poo',
  '12hell',
  'hell123',
  // Won't match
  'hello',
  'spoon'
].forEach(w => console.log(`'${w}': ${regex.test(w)}`));
```

Comment: So I need to make a blacklist? Is there a way I can just make a whitelist?